# Does the math subject GRE exam contains a graph paper and a calculator or no.

Tags: soft-question, gre-exam

I know that the math subject GRE exam is a paper based test, but does this paper contains a graph paper? I also have read(not sure from the source) that calculators are not allowed on this test, even simple ones, am I right?

Comment: Calculators were not allowed when I took the GRE, but that was Quite A While Ago.

Comment: It's been a very long time, so perhaps my memory is failing me, but I don't recall anything on the math subject GRE where either a calculator or graph paper would have helped.